# MAAS detected disks de1GB and Landscape detects nodes but with checklists(X)

Tags: maas, disk, detect

My problem is that MAAS, with hard drives does not recognize your storage capacity, and continue with the installation checklist landscape in brand teams recognize but with a red X.

Equipment features:

```
maas:
  Install: 1.7.5+bzr3369-0ubuntu1~trusty1
- list:
  - lldp:lldp:
    label: LLDP neighbors
  - lshw:list:
    - lshw:node:
      id: escorpion
      claimed: true
      class: system
      handle: DMI:0100
      - lshw:description:
        Computer
      - lshw:product:
        ProLiant DL360 G5
      - lshw:vendor:
        HP
      - lshw:width:
        units: bits
        64
lshw:node:
          id: cpu:0
 lshw:product:
            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU            5160  @ 3.00GHz
```

Disk

```
lshw:node:
              id: storage
              claimed: true
              class: storage
              handle: SCSI:02
              - lshw:description:
                RAID bus controller
              - lshw:product:
                Smart Array Controller
              - lshw:vendor:
                Hewlett-Packard Company
              - lshw:physid:
                0
              - lshw:businfo:
                pci@0000:06:00.0
              - lshw:logicalname:
                scsi2
              - lshw:version:
                01
              - lshw:width:
                units: bits
                64
              - lshw:clock:
                units: Hz
                33000000
              - lshw:configuration:
                - lshw:setting:
                  id: driver
                  value: cciss
                - lshw:setting:
                  id: latency
                  value: 0
              - lshw:capabilities:
                - lshw:capability:
                  id: storage
                - lshw:capability:
                  id: pciexpress
                  PCI Express
                - lshw:capability:
                  id: msix
                  MSI-X
                - lshw:capability:
                  id: pm
                  Power Management
                - lshw:capability:
                  id: vpd
                  Vital Product Data
                - lshw:capability:
                  id: bus_master
                  bus mastering
                - lshw:capability:
                  id: cap_list
                  PCI capabilities listing
                - lshw:capability:
                  id: rom
                  extension ROM
                - lshw:capability:
                  id: scsi-host
                  SCSI host adapter
              - lshw:resources:
                - lshw:resource:
                  type: irq
                  value: 16
                - lshw:resource:
                  type: memory
                  value: fdd00000-fddfffff
                - lshw:resource:
                  type: ioport
                  value: 4000(size=256)
                - lshw:resource:
                  type: memory
                  value: fdcf0000-fdcf0fff
                - lshw:resource:
                  type: memory
                  value: d0100000-d013ffff
```